# Azure Input Event Arrival Early

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am stuck at the Input Event Arrival Earlier in azure stream analytics.
My input for Stream Analytics from Azure Event Hub and output is in CosmosDB.

Now the problem is I am collecting data offline as well. so when the user is connected back to interne, I am sending data to azure. it giving me an error as mention below.

**Late input event**, so for that I have increase accept late event time up to 3 days.

and now it's giving me the error as mention below

**Input event arrival time is earlier than input event application timestamp  by more than 5 minutes**

anyone have idea to fix such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the timestamp of a data point (the value in the column used by the Timestamp by statement) is greater than the wall-clock of the processing system, by more than an allowed threshold (5 mins).

One possible cause of such would be timezones - note that ASA works in UTC, so the timestamp must be in UTC, or have the timezone according to ISO 8601.

Another possible cause, is that the senders clock is significantly skewed, but the threshold is quite large, so this is less probable than the above.

Comment: Hi, Sasha Alperovich, thanks for the hint. but still, I am confused in 1 situation. it allowed me with the difference of 10:30 hours when I am sending data online, then why it not allowing when sending offline data which will be sent later when connected back to the internet. how can it possible ?

Comment: Please include a sample of your input event, so I can check

Comment: Please check on the below link for sample data with the timestamp
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1mFRXPgOL-9s8eGlT9-HWXXzzA4WQVZMc